# WXR import problem — not including categories

Tags: import, bulk-import

I’m trying to import into Wordpress a WXR file with many hundreds of Posts. It works fine and during the import process it seems to understand the categories, but the imported Posts are eventually just given the Uncategorized category. I’m using the WordPress Importer plugin.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using the importer but this sounds a bit like a bug. The importers have been moved out of core into plugins on their own, but you can still do bug reports in wordpress trac about them. Have you considered to report the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the answer: http://mansurovs.com/tech/wordpress-does-not-import-categories-and-tags (from there) :

1. Make sure not to delete the original “Hello World!” post that gets automatically created by WordPress. If you have already deleted it, create a new dummy post that you can later delete.
2. Make sure that the WordPress import process is successfully finished.
3. After all posts and pages have been imported, go to “Edit” under “Posts” and edit the “Hello World!” or dummy post.
4. Go through each of the categories and put a checkmark in front of every single category.
5. Save the post.
6. Visit both the “Categories” page in the admin section and the main page and make sure that all categories show up correctly with the correct number of posts attached to them.